# Codeigniter 2.0 default controller for sub folder not working in server but working in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have set up a virtual host in my local machine (assume it to be http://local.he). I have a `home.php` in the main ‘controllers’ folder. I have two subfolders inside the ‘controllers’ folder and they are ‘admin’ and ‘wori’ and each has a `home.php` file.

Per CI 2.0 structure, if I access http://local.he/module/wori then it should load `home.php` from ‘wori’ and it is working but when I did the same in the server after uploading the files it always loads from module. Even if I access something like this: http://site.com/module/wori/users, it is still loading the `home.php` from module.

Here is the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|static)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here is the routing and these two are the only executable lines in `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

When I try to access http://site.com/module/index.php/wori or http://site.com/module/index.php/wori/users then it works. I checked `.htaccess` and it is working for other modules in my site. I even tried this example: [CodeIgniter default controller in a sub directory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working) but this is still not working:

```
$route['wori'] = 'wori/home';
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the answer from the following url and it worked for me.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181149/#857629

yet would like to know why it was working normally like in the localhost.