# Codeigniter sub-folder controller working in localhost but not in server throwing 404 not found error

Tags: codeigniter

[Codeigniter 2.0 default controller for sub folder not working in server but working in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654168/codeigniter-2-0-default-controller-for-sub-folder-not-working-in-server-but-work)

Dear all, I face the exact same issue as the above thread. I can see that the problem has been solved, but following the link provided; I cannot find the solution.

Any other people have the solution? please share. Thank you.

Comment: If it's because the link in the other answer is 404, does this help? https://web.archive.org/web/20120120211630/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181149/#857629

Comment: In routes default controller should not be in sub folder as it was a bug in codeigniter 2 versions I was told on codeigniter forum. That bug is now fixed in codeigniter 3 will not be allowed to add subfolder in codeigniter 3 default_controller in routes unless use hmvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old forum from CodeIgniter has been integrated into the new one. You can check all similar posts in CI archives.
The new URL for this is

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-38657.html

Hope this helps!