# CodeIgniter routes issues to access the frontend and backend folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have frontend and backend folder inside controllers and views. I tried server steps even check almost all the solution but still I am not able to access it my default controller

[image]

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/User_control';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

/*backend*********************************/
  $config['backend'] = 'backend/Access_control';
```

1) My issue is When I am accessing the Url http://localhost/example_ci_row/

I am getting 404 Page not found

[image]

2) How to access the backend URL I tried http://localhost/icube_row/admin
 but I am getting the error

[image]

**frontend User_control**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_control extends CI_Controller {
    public $current_date;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('frontend/login');
    }
    }
?>
```

**Backend Access control**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Access_control extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');           
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('backend/login');
    }

    }

?>
```

**Edited**

It's working when I use below steps. I added the Test.php file in the controller and change the routes then I am getting the login page.

**Test.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public $current_date;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('frontend/login');
    }
    }
?>
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Test';
```

Comment: May be .htaccess file is missing. please check it once

Comment: @PravinVavadiya,htaccess file is already available in my application folder. Should I create outside of the application?

Comment: I think, There might be some issue with routes.

Comment: The built in $route['default_controller'] will not work for sub-folders. you have to extend system router as per your requirements

Comment: @pradeep, Can you help me with more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

The built in `$route['default_controller']` will not work for sub-folders. you have to extend system router as per your requirements like this :

You need to create a `MY_Router.php` in `application > core > MY_Router.php`

```
<?php

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
    protected function _set_default_controller() {

        if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

            show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
        }
        // Is the method being specified?
        if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }

        // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory
        if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

            // Set the class as the directory

            $this->set_directory($class);

            // $method is the class

            $class = $method;

            // Re check for slash if method has been set

            if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
                $method = 'index';
            }
        }

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

            // This will trigger 404 later

            return;
        }
        $this->set_class($class);
        $this->set_method($method);
        // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
        $this->uri->rsegments = array(
            1 => $class,
            2 => $method
        );
        log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use `$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/User_control';` as your default controller

Comment: Yes, It's working. How is it working? can you help me out?

Comment: as i told you by default The built in $route['default_controller'] will not work for sub-folders. you have to extend system router as per your requirements

Comment: my default controller is working using your MY_Router code but how to access the backend controller?

Comment: Yes, sure I will accept it and upvote it your answer, but give me some time to implement in my code. default_controller is working but  $config['backend'] = 'backend/Access_control';  is not working

Comment: Oh!! God I added $config instated of the route. that's the reason it's not working. Now It's working perfectly. thanks and upvote from my side.

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding

Comment: I just want to know where should I add the .htaccess file inside the application for outside application? which is the best?

Comment: outside the application folder parallel to example_ci_row folder

Comment: Cool!! Thank you

Comment: I hope you are doing well, I know it's not a good way to redirect any member to the question but trust me I am solving one issue from the last 4 days. if you know any think on this please let me know. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977036/how-to-display-the-array-inside-array-output

Comment: Yes, You suggested to me and that is working. I just need to know if I have to access the samename value then how can I access it? I tried print_r($row->somename[0]->disbursed); but it's not working.

Comment: @user9437856 you got to access like this  `foreach($value->somename as $item){ echo $item->disbursed;}`

Comment: Thanks for this, I am already in foreach and I tried $row->somename[0]->filesubmit again and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the  `Base URL` ?
**Application->config->config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/example_ci_row';
```

Comment: I think, There might be some issue with routes

Comment: To fix other issues we need to clarify that default controller is working. When you try `http://localhost/example_ci_row` in your address bar, it cannot display any error according to these settings.

Comment: Yes, default controller is working but It is working when I add the controller outside of the frontend and backend folder.

Comment: I found an previous answer here for your problem. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working

Comment: I already tried that before asking the question. If I hit the URL http://localhost/example_ci_row/index.php/frontend/User_control    then I am getting the my login page but When I hit the URL http://localhost/example_ci_row/  then It's getting 404 page not found

Comment: Have you created a `.htaccess` file and configured config file like this; `$config['index_page'] = ' ';` ?

Comment: Yes, I have created the .htaccess inside my root(example_ci_row) folder and $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/example_ci_row'; $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';   My .htaccess file is emply now. should I add any code?

Comment: `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` this should be like this `$config['index_page'] = '';` You should remove `index.php` that is there inside `''`

Comment: Yes, I remove the index.php and added  code in the htacess which you provided but still I am not able to access the $route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/User_control'; still getting 404 page not found