# Object not found in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

A few months ago I asked a question on SO  related to route issue.

[CodeIgniter routes issues to access the frontend and backend folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874542/codeigniter-routes-issues-to-access-the-frontend-and-backend-folder)

After adding the answer in my code my issue got resolved.

Now, I created a controller called as `Menu_controlle` in the `frontend` folder and created a `services.php` file inside `frontend` on view.

***Menu_control***

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Menu_control extends CI_Controller {
  public $current_date;
  function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $this->current_date= date('d-m-Y H:i:s');      
    }
 public function index()
  {
   $this->load->view('frontend/home');
  }
  public function services()
  {
   $this->load->view('frontend/services');
  }
}
?>
```

I added in the menu

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Menu_control/services');?>">Our Servces</a></li>
```

Now when I click on Our service menu then It gives me "object Not found" error.
[image]

[image]
Can anyone know my I am getting this error?
.htaccess file is empty.

Comment: The class name must match the controller's file name. If the class is `Menu_control` the file should be `Menu_control.php` not `Menu_controlle.php`

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, Yes, I edited my question. I have the same name.

Comment: oh ok... and does the view exist? the 404 could be for either the controller (which doesn't seem to be the case) or the view. Is the PHP file for the view created under `views/frontend/services`?

Comment: Yes, view/frontend/services file exists in the view. Even my index function is working but not able to access the other page. If I user  public function index()
  {
   $this->load->view('frontend/services');
  } 

Then it's working

Answer (score 0):

try [PrettyURL](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) for your project.
write following code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

or you can also use following codeigniter basic url

```
{{domain}}/index.php/{{controller_name}}/{{method_name}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added your code in htaccess and I am getting an error 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: try basic url as i have provided

Comment: I tried http://localhost/foldername/Menu_control/services, It gives me an error, Than I tried http://localhost/foldername/index.php/Menu_control/services then also same error.

Comment: then check file name and class name under this file that both should be same.if still not work then try something dump print and exit; in __cunstruct function to check class is works or not.

Comment: The class name is same. I added exit(); in the __construct and it's working now what is the next process?

Comment: now you have to understand where is your errors. (may be in global variable)

Comment: My helper is $autoload['helper'] = array('form','url','file');

Comment: if you have already autoload 'form and url' then why are you trying to again load it in constructor? remove it.

Comment: I remove it now. @Vrushabh, I just want to know the htaccess code. I have two htaccess file one is inside application and one is outside project. I added your code outside of the project

Comment: As for files not being accessible within the application folder, that's due to a .htaccess file in that folder denying all access in general. To prevent unintended file exposal.

Comment: Yes, denying the file .  Even my index function is working but not able to access the other page. If I user public function index() { $this->load->view('frontend/services'); } Then it's working

Comment: Not till now. I am still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try below code in .htaccess file of your root folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Replace the folder_name with your project folder name.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Folder structure and Menu_control.php file.

[image]

It's working for me.
Root folder's .htaccess file contains the code i have provided earlier.

[image]

**Updated htaccess file with folder name**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added your code in htaccess but still getting the same issue

Comment: Which htaccess have you updated?There are two .htaccess files one is in the application folder and another one outside of application folder(i.e. into root folder).

Comment: Yes, I updated root htaccess which is outside of the application folder

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me. Can you share your htaccess code with folder name?

Comment: @user9437856..Yes i have updated the answer.you can certainly look into it.

Comment: Give me some time to implement your code.. Reply you soon

Comment: @user9437856..No its not actually.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me. I am deleting CI and downloading again and then I will try your code. So give me some time. I will update you. Please

Comment: @user9437856..yes please do fresh installation.

Comment: I tried your code after fresh installation but still not working. Can you share the controller folder image?

Comment: @user9437856..Okay then access the url as "base_url/index.php/menu_control/services".See if it works.

Comment: I have backend and frontend folder in view as well as on controller. If I directly call Menu_control then it's working but If I add backend/Menu_control then it's not working. This is my image folder path https://i.stack.imgur.com/frkdG.png  I updated the controller name from menu_controler to Access_control