# Default controller isn't working with controller sub directories in Codeigniter 3.1.10

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have sub directories under controllers folder like this:

```
controllers
--main
----home.php
----login.php
--admin
----home.php
----login.php
```

**So how to make the default controller load *main/home.php* when entering "example.com" ?**

As I read from this [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#directories-and-default-controller-404-override) that I can't add a directory in $route['default_controller'] in CI 3.
So I did this:

In config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['Home'] = "main/home";
```

In config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.example.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So when I type example.com CI won't redirect me to *main/home.php*
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you access the `main/home` statically? Have you tried `$route['default_controller'] = 'main/home';` ?

Comment: Yes I can access main/home statically, and yes I've tried '$route['default_controller'] = 'main/home'' and didn't work because directories don't work in CI-3

Comment: Why not create a defined core-controller which redirects you with folders/subfolders rotues and extend it to your Controller? :) Just an idea.

Comment: The MY_Router.php in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working appears to work. I've tried it and it "appears" to work for what you want.