# Codeigniter 4 subdirectory controller not accessible on remote server

Tags: codeigniter-4

I just almost completed project in `Codeigniter 4` and published it on hosting server. And now I am not able to access controller that is inside subdirectory.

For example:
http://localhost/admin/auth/ - this URL works fine.

And when I access it on hosting server:
http://x.someserver.com/admin/auth/

Then I am getting this error:

[image]

It's trying to load `admin` controller which doesn't exist. Here is how my controllers are structured:

Note: `Root.php` is my default controller.

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. Or how can to resolve this.
Here what I have found online similar issues.

One states that it needs to be namespaced.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working

Comment: What's your `$baseURL` inside `Config\App` and what do your routes look like?

Comment: @parttimeturtle for localhost it's `http://localhost:8080` and on remote server Its `http://x.someserver.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot of your filesystem shows your `admin/` directory is all lower case.  It should start with a capital `A`.  [From the docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories):

> #### Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-directories
>
> If you are building a large application you might want to hierarchically organize or structure your controllers into sub-directories. CodeIgniter permits you to do this.
>
> Simply create sub-directories under the main `app/Controllers/` one and place your controller classes within them.
>
> #### Important
>
> Folder names MUST start with an uppercase letter and ONLY the first character can be uppercase.

If you would rather use lower case `a`, or if you simply want more transparent control of your routing, [set up routes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html).